# MySQL select where timestamps don't overlap

Tags: mysql

Each user has multiple bookings against them in a table, I need to get the users details and the booking details, where the booking start and end date doesn't overlap with the date the user passed.

**users**

```
id | name
---------
1  | Ryan
2  | Dave
```

**user_bookings**

```
id | user_id | title         | start_date | end_date
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | Booking One   | 1484133562 | 1484133562
2  | 1       | Booking Two   | 1484133562 | 1484133562
3  | 2       | Booking Three | 1484133562 | 1484133562
```

The site user can search for users who **DONT** have bookings during the times they specify. So they could search for dates like: `01/01/2017` till `05/01/2017` and if user_id 1 has a booking during that time, they wont show up in the results.

I have a query currently like:

```
SELECT 
users.name, 
user_bookings.name 
FROM users 
JOIN user_bookings ON users.id = user_bookings.user_id
WHERE NOT(('$start_date' <= user_bookings.start_date) AND (user_bookings.end_date <= '$end_date')) GROUP BY users.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.name, user_bookings.name 
FROM users 
JOIN user_bookings ON users.id = user_bookings.user_id
WHERE NOT ((DATE_FORMAT(user_bookings.start_date,'%m/%d/%Y') >= '$start_date' AND DATE_FORMAT(user_bookings.end_date,'%m/%d/%Y') <= '$end_date')) AND users.id = 1
GROUP BY users.id;
```